# Understanding Spring's Web Reactive Framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactive

I am currently developing an application with **SpringBoot 2**, **spring-boot-starter-webflux** on netty and **jOOQ**.
Below is the code that I have come up with after hours of research and stackoverflow searches. I have built in a lot of
logging in order to see what's happening on which thread.

**UserController:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Integer>> createUser(@RequestBody ImUser user) {
    return Mono.just(user)
            .map(it -> {
                logger.debug("Receiving request on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return it;
            })
            .map(userService::create)
            .map(it -> {
                logger.debug("Sending response on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(it);
            })
            .mapError(DuplicateKeyException.class, e -> new SomeSpecialException(e.getMessage(), e));
}
```

**UserService:**

```
public int create(ImUser user) {
    return Mono.just(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .map(u -> {
                logger.debug("UserService thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return imUserDao.insertUser(u);
            })
            .block();
}
```

**UserDao:**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public int insertUser(ImUser user) {
    logger.debug("Insert DB on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return dsl.insertInto(IM_USER,IM_USER.VERSION, IM_USER.FIRST_NAME, IM_USER.LAST_NAME, IM_USER.BIRTHDATE, IM_USER.GENDER)
            .values(1, user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getBirthdate(), user.getGender())
            .returning(IM_USER.ID)
            .fetchOne()
            .getId();
}
```

The code works as expected, "Receiving request" and "Sending response" both run on the same thread (**reactor-http-server-epoll-x**)
while the blocking code ( the call to *imUserDao.insertUser(u)* ) runs on an elastic Scheduler thread (**elastic-x**). 
The transaction is bound to the thread on which the annotated method is called (which is elastic-x) and thus works as expected (I have tested 
it with a different method which is not posted here, to keep things simple).

Here is a **log sample**:

```
20:57:21,384 DEBUG         admin.UserController| Receiving request on thread: reactor-http-server-epoll-7
20:57:21,387 DEBUG            admin.UserService| UserService thread: elastic-2
20:57:21,391 DEBUG        admin.ExtendedUserDao| Insert DB on thread: elastic-2
20:57:21,393 DEBUG         tools.LoggerListener| Executing query          
...
20:57:21,401 DEBUG              tools.StopWatch| Finishing                : Total: 9.355ms, +3.355ms
20:57:21,409 DEBUG         admin.UserController| Sending response on thread: reactor-http-server-epoll-7
```

I have researched reactive programming for a long time now, but never quite got to program anything reactive. Now that I am, I am wondering if I am doing it correctly.
So here are my questions:

**1.** Is the code above a good way to handle incoming HTTP requests, query the DB and then respond? 
Please ignore the logger.debug(...) calls which I have built in for the sake of my sanity :) I kind of expected to have a **Flux< ImUser>** as the argument to the controller method, in the sense that I have a stream of multiple potential requests
that will come at some point and will all be handled in the same way. Instead, the examples that I have found create a **Mono.from(...);** every time a request comes in.

**2.** The second Mono created in the UserService ( **Mono.just(user)** ) feels somewhat awkward. I understand that I need to start a new stream to be able to 
run code on the elastic Scheduler, but isn't there an operator that does this?

**3.** From the way the code is written, I understand that the Mono inside the UserService will be blocked until the DB operation finishes,
 but the original stream, which serves the requests, isn't blocked. Is this correct?

**4.** I plan to replace **Schedulers.elastic()** with a parallel Scheduler where I can configure the number of worker threads. The idea is that the number of maximum worker threads should be the same as maximum DB connections.
 What will happen when all worker threads inside the Scheduler will be busy? Is that when backpressure jumps in?

**5.** I initially expected to have this code inside my controller:

```
return userService.create(user)
            .map(it -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(it))
            .mapError(DuplicateKeyException.class, e -> new SomeSpecialException(e.getMessage(), e));
```

but I have not been able to achieve that AND keep the things running in the correct threads. Is there any way to achieve this inside my code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Service and Controller**
The fact that your service is blocking is problematic, because then in the controller you are calling a blocking method from inside a `map` that isn't moved on a separate thread. This has the potential to block **all** controllers.

What you could do instead is return a `Mono` from `UserService#create` (remove the `block()` at the end). Since the service ensures that the Dao method call is isolated, it is less problematic. From there, no need to do `Mono.just(user)` in the Controller: just call create and start chaining operators directly on the resulting Mono:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Integer>> createUser(@RequestBody ImUser user) {
    //this log as you saw was executed in the same thread as the controller method
    logger.debug("Receiving request on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return userService.create(user)
        .map(it -> {
            logger.debug("Sending response on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(it);
        })
        .mapError(DuplicateKeyException.class, e -> new SomeSpecialException(e.getMessage(), e));
}
```

**Logging**
Note that if you want to log something there are a couple better options than doing a `map` and returning `it`:

- `doOnNext` method is tailored for that: react to one of the reactive signals (in this instance, `onNext`: a value is emitted) and perform some non-mutating action, leaving the output sequence exactly the same as the source sequence. The "side-effect" of the doOn can be writing to the console or incrementing statistic counters for instance... There's also doOnComplete, doOnError, doOnSubscribe, doOnCancel, etc...
- `log` simply logs all events in the sequence above it. It will detect if you use SLF4J and use the configured logger at DEBUG level if so. Otherwise it'll use the JDK Logging features (so you also need to configure that to display DEBUG level logs).

**A word about transactions** or rather anything relying on `ThreadLocal`
ThreadLocal and thread-stickiness can be problematic in reactive programming, because there's less guarantee of the underlying execution model staying the same throughout a whole sequence. A `Flux` can execute in several steps, each in a different `Scheduler` (and so thread or thread pool). Even at a specific step, one value could be processed by thread A of the underlying thread pool while the next one, arriving later on, would be processed on thread B.

Relying on Thread Local is less straightforward in this context, and we are currently actively working on providing alternatives that fit better in the reactive world.

Your idea of making a pool of the size of the connection pool is good, but not necessarily sufficient, with the potential of several threads being used by a transactional flux, thus maybe polluting some threads with the transaction.

**What happens when a pool runs out of threads**
If you are using a particular `Scheduler` to isolate blocking behavior like here, once it runs out of threads it would throw a `RejectedExecutionException`.

Comment: Hi Simon. Thank you for the reply.  
  
I have implemented the Controller / UserService as you suggested. Actually I have done that before, but that means that the response is sent back on the elastic thread.  
I was previously fixated on having the response end on the same thread as the request. I wanted the threads on the Scheduler to have only one responsibility, which is DB work. But I now somehow feel it is ok for it to end on the elastic thread. It doesn't really make any difference.  
(OMG why can't I write longer comments?)

Comment: I understand the ThreadLocal problematic. It makes sense. But in my example, I think it should be ok. I mean, as long as I don't chain operators with separate transactional code blocks and keep everything ThreadLocal-related inside one call, like in imUserDao.insertUser(u), I should be fine. Right?  
Or would you recommend completely avoiding Transactions and/or ThreadLocal stuff inside the Web Reactive Framework? Or at least for now ...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake with the **.block();**. That was actually the reason for my 3rd question. I thought that was only blocking the Mono inside the UserService on the elastic thread and then returning the value to the initial thread. I didn't think it would also block the initial thread.  
   
**@Transactional Flux** - are there any examples I can check out?  
  
**@Logging**, yes I know it was bad :) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Transaction support is still work in progress I'd say, in the sense that it needs you to understand how underlying execution works, eg if you don't publishOn explicitly, there will be work stealing and the rest of the execution will stay on the previous thread

Comment: Hi Guys. I was wondering if there are some news about transaction management in reactive streams ?

Comment: @cambierr I asked a similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934357/does-spring-transaction-management-work-with-spring-webflux