# Spring webflux jpa transaction

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I'm using spring data jpa and webflux and now i have problem with tranasction.
Is there a way using jpa and webflux to manage tranasction? 
I'm using spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE version

```
@Transactional
    public Mono<Entity> saveDimension(Entity entity) {
        return databaseService.call(() -> repository.saveAndFlush(entity))
                                                       .doOnNext(a -> {
                                                           throw new RuntimeException("test");
                                                       });
    }

@Transactional
@Service
public class DatabaseService {
    private Scheduler jdbcSchedluer;

    public DatabaseService(@Qualifier("jdbcScheduler") Scheduler jdbcSchedluer) {
        this.jdbcSchedluer = jdbcSchedluer;
    }

    public <T> Mono<T> call(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            return supplier.get();
        }).subscribeOn(this.jdbcSchedluer);
    }
}
```

With this code it save the entity on db and doesn't rollback as expected

edit: pom

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail which problems do you have? Need some code snippets, error messages, etc.

Comment: I added some snippet

Comment: Could you also include your `pom.xml`?

Comment: i added the significant dependencies. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Maybe something like `spring-data-r2dbc` is needed here. I'm only guessing now.

Comment: I know but, as i know, it's not production ready and i need some feature like specification that are not present on r2dbc.

Comment: you can't use @Transactional annotation in Webflux, it uses ThreadLocal.

Comment: I suspected that. So the only way is to use programmatically transaction?

Comment: As I know  - yes

Comment: ok, i'll try with this. thanks

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934357/does-spring-transaction-management-work-with-spring-webflux